# When I check the value of a function in conditional statements, the value is different to that of the variable I returned

Tags: python

I have a function that's designed to randomly generate numbers from 1 - 6, with some other conditions. I save the number to a variable called 'turn', and later return this when the function ('turnSelector()') is called.

The weird part:
Later I use conditional statements to check which value (1-6) turnSelector() is equal to. I was getting a non-random distribution, so I threw in an else statement to see if turnSelector() = values that weren't 1-6, and then print these so I could see what they were. The else statement was used, and the values printed were between 1-6 (inclusive).

If I global 'turn' and use that in the conditional statements, I get a distribution expected with random generation, and no weird other values with the else statement.

So, why is turnSelector() returning different values to 'turn', even though I am returning 'turn'?!

```
def turnSelector():
global save1, save2, save3, turn

selection = False
while selection == False:
    turn = randint(1,6)

    save1, save2, save3 = turn, save1, save2

    if turn == save1 == save2 == save3:
        continue
    else:
        selection = True
        return turn
```

This produces the non-random distribution:

```
def turnExecutor():
    global scrambledState, zero, one, two, three, four, five,six
    if turnSelector()== 1:
        scrambledState = anterior(scrambledState)
        zero += 1
    elif turnSelector()== 2:
        scrambledState = posterior(scrambledState)
        one += 1
    elif turnSelector()== 3:
        scrambledState = dorsal(scrambledState)
        two += 1
    elif turnSelector()== 4:
        scrambledState = ventral(scrambledState)
        three += 1
    elif turnSelector()== 5:
        scrambledState = right(scrambledState)
        four += 1
    elif turnSelector()== 6:
        scrambledState = left(scrambledState)
        five += 1
    else:
        six += 1
        print(str(turnSelector()))
```

This produces the random distribution I want:

```
def turnExecutor():
global scrambledState, zero, one, two, three, four, five,six
if turn == 1:
    scrambledState = anterior(scrambledState)
    zero += 1
elif turn == 2:
    scrambledState = posterior(scrambledState)
    one += 1
elif turn == 3:
    scrambledState = dorsal(scrambledState)
    two += 1
elif turn == 4:
    scrambledState = ventral(scrambledState)
    three += 1
elif turn == 5:
    scrambledState = right(scrambledState)
    four += 1
elif turn == 6:
    scrambledState = left(scrambledState)
    five += 1
# (no need for else as only 1-6 values)
```

Comment: Why are you calling `turnSelector()` over and over?

Comment: Because every time you call turnSelector, it changes the value of turn. And the variable  `selection` is always `False` because your code sets it to `False`not a global variable, so its value is reinitialised each time. BTW it is bad style to compare a boolean variable with `False` or `True`, you only need to do e.g. `while not selection:`

Comment: BTW to debug this yourself, all you had to do is immediately before the return statement in turnSelector(), `print turn`.

Comment: Also, read how to ask a question about problems with code here https://www.stackoverflow.com/mcve BEFORE posting your next question.

Comment: It seems like you're expecting Python functions to be "pure functions" that always return the same value when called with the same arguments (in this case, no arguments at all). Python _allows_ that, but doesn't _force_ it; if you want to write a function that returns a different random value each time, you can. And that's exactly what you've done.

Comment: @user2357112 because I'm a noob and don't really know what I'm doing. What should I do instead?

Comment: @barny, thanks, I will change my code so it doesn't call the function every time. I am meant to reinitialise 'selection' every time so that is cool. I'm confused about 'while not selection'... Is there something i can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if turnSelector()== 1:
    scrambledState = anterior(scrambledState)
    zero += 1
elif turnSelector()== 2:
    scrambledState = posterior(scrambledState)
    one += 1
```

This doesn't look right to me. You call `turnSelector` in each of your conditionals, which means it can return a different value each time. You have a (5/6)^6 chance that none of your conditionals will pass, and the `else` will execute. Try calling `turnSelector` once, and storing the result, and comparing against that stored result in your conditionals.

```
def turnExecutor():
    global scrambledState, zero, one, two, three, four, five,six
    x = turnSelector()
    if x== 1:
        scrambledState = anterior(scrambledState)
        zero += 1
    elif x== 2:
        scrambledState = posterior(scrambledState)
        one += 1
    elif x == 3:
        scrambledState = dorsal(scrambledState)
        two += 1
    elif x== 4:
        scrambledState = ventral(scrambledState)
        three += 1
    elif x== 5:
        scrambledState = right(scrambledState)
        four += 1
    else:
        scrambledState = left(scrambledState)
        five += 1
```